# Info about an idea of making my own chatbot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arduino, raspberry-pi, dialogflow-es, chatbot

integrate api.ai 
[Integrating api.ai chatbot on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349095/integrating-api-ai-chatbot-on-a-website)

Having troubles with doing research on an idea I have and want to do.

There are two vesrions in my opinion: 
1) with physical device 
2) as integrated chatbot

1) Basically I want to make my own physical device which will be used almost as an assistant, takes voice commands and makes a request to my API, outputs the response also as voice. I am familiar to RaspberryPi and Arduino since I am aware it will take a microphone module, wifi and everything else needed.

2) Integrated chatbot means I will implement it as a web app with an iframe.

---

As far as my knowledge goes, I have experience with developing APIs with Microsoft technologies, C++ for Raspberry although I have never used a Raspberry and I have read the documentation for Dialogflow being the, in my opinion, best option for assistant bot. I have successfully made a demo as seen in this video --> 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cD9vU7Ubyg&t=9s

Now, I need help from somebody to help me connect the dots. Some perhaps tips, tricks what is preferable, what is the flow of the whole communication between the device if implemented and my API...

Any information is helpful in some hand since everything is a variable, from technology since I am open to some new frameworks and so on, to way of implementation, if perhaps you've done such things and you have encountered some problems of any kind, or maybe while reading this you've had an idea and want to share it with me :D

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it, point is if its a choice of framework, you use anything, be it MS bot framework, wit.ai, api.ai (dialogflow), etc., selection solely depends on what they have to offer. NLP is just a parsing engine which tells you the context of what user wants to say, nothing beyond that. If I had to choose, I would check, following points & then decide.

**1. Pricing Model 2. Output Precision 3. API/SDK Availability 4. Multilingual 5.audio support 6. ML configurations 7. Social media integrations 8. SmallTalk 9. ML Configuration**

In my personal opinion, api.ai is lot more flexible to use & have free standard plan as well. MS bot framework, on the contrary, is paid & have lots new features including dispatcher services etc. to offer, more compatible to use with MS cognitive services. Now coming to connecting dots, I think, flow of communication would be,

*Recorder --> Capture the command --> Get it transcribed --> Send it to NLP --> Webhook (your business logic resides here) --> Check the intent called --> Service to take action --> Device takes the action --> successful? send a response back to NLP --> Send it caller service --> Responds back (I took an action for you!)*

I hope this helps, thanks,